# How to merge array in php and json?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array like

```
$data1 = array(
    ['Ngay'=>'15-10-2013','esoluz'=>'5'],
    ['Ngay'=>'16-10-2013','esoluz'=>'3'],
    ['Ngay'=>'17-10-2013','esoluz'=>'7']
);

$data2 = array(
    ['Ngay'=>'15-10-2013','google'=>'10'],
    ['Ngay'=>'16-10-2013','google'=>'8']
);
```

I want it to become:

```
$result = array(
    ['Ngay'=>'15-10-2013','esoluz'=>'5','google'=>'10'],
    ['Ngay'=>'16-10-2013','esoluz'=>'3','google'=>'8'],
    ['Ngay'=>'17-10-2013','esoluz'=>'7'],
)
```

Because i need an array like the $result to json_encode it to use in making a graph but it makes me confused. So, thanks for any helpful idea !

Comment: And be careful with the [] within array(). They will throw a parse error at ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$outArray = array();
foreach($data1 as $item){
    $outArray[$item['Ngay']] = $item;
}
foreach($data2 as $item){
    if(array_key_exists($item['Ngay'],$outArray)){
        $outArray[$item['Ngay']] = array_merge($outArray[$item['Ngay']],$item);
    }else{
         $outArray[$item['Ngay']] = $item;
    }
}
```

PHP fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v8f-miu

Answer (score 3):

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2ce9d28f355660ec621d952c448614997f0b4a6

```
$data1 = array(
    ['Ngay'=>'15-10-2013','esoluz'=>'5'],
    ['Ngay'=>'16-10-2013','esoluz'=>'3'],
    ['Ngay'=>'17-10-2013','esoluz'=>'7']
);

$data2 = array(
    ['Ngay'=>'15-10-2013','google'=>'10'],
    ['Ngay'=>'16-10-2013','google'=>'8']
);
// Yet a working function
function yawf($arr1, $arr2) {
    $result = array();
    $temp = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $k => $v) {
        $temp[$v['Ngay']] = $v;
    };

    foreach($arr2 as $k => $v) {
        if(isset($temp[$v['Ngay']])) {
            $temp[$v['Ngay']]['google'] = $v['google'];
        }
        else {
            $temp[$v['Ngay']] = $v;
        }
    };

    foreach($temp as $k => $v) {
        $result[] = $v;
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(yawf($data1, $data2));

echo json_encode(yawf($data1, $data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) after that use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to make the unique value and than print the JSON result. Your code will be like -

```
$result_arr = array_merge($data2, $data1);
$result_arr = array_unique($result_arr);
```

```
$result_arr = array();
foreach($data1 as $value){
    $result_arr[$value['Ngay']] = $value;
}
foreach($data2 as $value){
    if(array_key_exists($value['Ngay'],$result_arr)){
        $result_arr[$value['Ngay']] = array_merge($result_arr[$value['Ngay']],$value);
    }else{
         $result_arr[$value['Ngay']] = $value;
    }
}
$result = json_encode($result_arr);
```

Comment: `array_unique` doesn't work with nested arrays. Elements are treated as strings so all arrays are treated as being duplicates and `$result_arr` will only have one element.

Comment: Oh yes, have not seen [] thanks.